# How do I print screen in windows 7 after I experience the problems below?

Tags: windows-7, print-screen

I know in Windows 7 that clicking the key labelled, "Print Scr" should print your current screen, for me this isn't working. Before you say it's my key that's to blame, prior to this I was using Ubuntu and I found that the print screen button was overly sensitive if anything.

Answer (score 6):

The <kbd>Print Scr</kbd> button will only copy the screen to your clipboard. It will seem like it did nothing, but it just saves an image of your screen to the clipboard.

You can then paste the image somewhere, for example, in Paint.

You could also download a program such as [FastStone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm), which will automatically save the image.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you! Rofl I feel quite silly now. Ubuntu makes a song and dance about it but Windows 7 doesn't, I forgot, it's been that long!

Comment: @BrentonHorne you're welcome :)

Comment: Jeez, I've been hitting Ctrl-Print Scr all these years not knowing the CTRL wasn't necessary!

Comment: It may be useful to note that pressing Alt+Print Scr will copy the currently focused window to the clipboard, rather than the entire display.

Comment: You don't necesserily require a custom program as Win 7 and above might include the "Snipping Tool" depending on your Windows edition. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/products/features/snipping-tool

Comment: @MrEdmundo Yes, but you have to click it, press "New Snip," choose which type of snip you want, do the actual snip, press save, navigate to where you want to save it, and finally save. That's 7 steps. With FastStone you just press a key and done. You don't even need to choose where to save, it automatically does it for you. You can set different key shortcuts for different types of captures (rectangular, window, full screen, etc.).

Comment: @Doorknob: All well and good, except for the price. Try Greenshot instead.

Comment: @Karan umm... It's free

Comment: @Doorknob: I see that the site *very* clearly mentions that FastStone Capture is *not* free but 30-day shareware.

Comment: @Karan I don't see that anywhere... It just says that you must buy a license to use it for commercial use. If it does say that somewhere, it's probably outdated, because I got it for free more than a month ago and it still works

Comment: @Doorknob: I think you are mixing up programs. See [this page](http://www.faststone.org/order.htm). As you can see, Image Viewer and Photo Resizer are free for personal/educational use whereas Capture and MaxView are 30-day shareware. You might have got a free license from somewhere, or an older version (v5.3 was the last free version before it became shareware), or perhaps only some features stop working after 30 days and you simply don't use them. Whatever the case, stating it's completely free is misleading. If people like it they should pay for it or use something else like I suggested.